# Remove exactly number of elements on automatic scroll down

Tags: jquery

I have a setInterval were i clone elements.
I use method `slice(0,4)` to select the first 4 elements and then use `remove()` to eliminate them from DOM when the scroll from top is greater than element height.
This works perfect but when i add a `setTimeout` function to start animating the scroll after 2 seconds when scroll bar apears, the moment when is about to remove it removes more elements than i give it.

```js
var i = 0;
var blackposition;
var square = $('<span></span>').first();

var endless = setInterval(function(){
var lungime = ($('span').height())/4;
console.log(lungime);
if(i%4==0){
blackposition = Math.floor(4*Math.random());
}

var math = (blackposition == (i%4))? 0 : 1;



square.clone().addClass('color_' + math).text((math < 1) ? 'even' + i : 'odd' + i).appendTo('#container');
i++;
setTimeout(function(){$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:'+='+ lungime + 'px' },500,'linear');},22000)

},500);




$(window).on('scroll',function(){
if( $("span").height() < $(window).scrollTop()+2){
$(window).scrollTop(0);
 $("span").slice(0,4).remove();
}})
```

```css
.color_0{
outline: 1px solid black;
width: 22%;
height: 10vh;
background-color: black;
color: white;
line-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;
  

}
.color_1{
outline: 1px solid black;
width: 22%;
height: 10vh;
background-color:white ;
line-height: 30px;
display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:gray; margin:0">
<div id="container" style=" height: 100%; width:20%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">

</div>
```

I guess this is because scroll bar doesn't start to 0 when elements are removed after delay. I write in my last lines to make scroll bar start to 0 when is about to remove but with no luck.

What can I do ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the extra 2 seconds, to keep the scroll bar behind by a row?

Comment: Yes. The bar appears after 20 seconds. I make the scroll bar wait 2 second before it starts scrolling down.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of why it removes more than 1 row the first time it scrolls down.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll handler at the base of your JS is firing when the window scrolls, and with the body being scrolled automatically, it is firing a lot, as in 40-50 times for each row of blocks you add.

As soon as your condition is met ($("span").height() < $(window).scrollTop() + 2), rows will be removed very quickly until the condition is no longer met.  That is why you see several rows removed all at once as soon as the 22 second countdown is up.  There are 3 rows to remove just to meet the height condition, after which it immediately removes a row every time a new row is added and the first scroll event occurs.

This fiddle uses your initial code and writes to the console output every time a row is removed:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/pk0yhzyp/  This should help you see what is happening after 22 seconds is up.

The line $(window).scrollTop(0); is not having any effect because it is being called after the scrolling has already happened, and then with the body scrolling automatically, it is called again every 40 ms or so.

If your goal is to remove a row every time a new row is added, but only after 20+2 seconds have passed so that the scroll bar is always a bit behind (i.e. the page is 1-2 rows taller than the viewport), you could remove the detection of the scroll and simply cut the rows in the loop, with a flag indicating when the initial delay is expired:

```
var i = 0;
var blackposition;
var square = $('<span></span>').first();
var removingRows = false; // Will be set once we can start removing rows

var endless = setInterval(function () {
    var lungime = ($('span').height()) / 4;
    console.log(lungime);
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        blackposition = Math.floor(4 * Math.random());
        // Remove a row every 4 blocks after flag has been set    
        if (removingRows) {
            $("span").slice(0, 4).remove();
        }
    }

    var math = (blackposition == (i % 4)) ? 0 : 1;

    square.clone().addClass('color_' + math).text((math < 1) ? 'even' + i : 'odd' + i).appendTo('#container');
    i++;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: '+=' + lungime + 'px'
        }, 500, 'linear');
        // Set flag so we can start removing rows
        removingRows = true;
    }, 22000)

}, 500);
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/na1729bo/

Comment: I thank you for explanation and the solution provided. This solve my issue to remove only 1 row at start after delay, however I dont want after that elements to be removed so roughly, I need to keep the scrolling bar so that elements can be scrolled down after this proportion:  $('span').height()) / 4

Comment: The "rough" effect you describe is due to the fact that you are adding a new row every 2 seconds, forcing the document height to increase suddenly.  If you are removing a row every time you add one, the document body jumps as the height increases.  If you do not remove rows (comment out $("span").slice(0, 4).remove();), the document is smooth but the scrollbar jumps as the height changes.  I don't see a way to prevent both of these "jumpy" effects.